# Can I post multiple answers for the sake of ease and clarity?

Tags: discussion, answers

This is regarding the question: [Is there a list of all typos in Hoffman and Kunze, Linear Algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/437253/279515)

The problem is that MathJax renders extremely slowly after my answers reach a certain length. At this point, [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2432064/279515) to the question is becoming impossible for me to edit and add more typos that I find. Is it alright if I post multiple answers, one for each chapter of the book, or will that be frowned upon by the community?

Comment: It renders well for me. I am not sure, but it might depend also on the computer you used?

Comment: @JohnMa i’m using a fairly new laptop, so I don’t think it’s my system. I have a good internet connection as well. It’s only the longer answers that give trouble.

Comment: I think it would be fine to start a second answer for typos beyond the ones already listed. Particularly if you indicate that you do it "for sake of ease and clarity". If the issue presents itself again once this second answer reaches comparable length to the current one, start a third answer and so on.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo : But if an errata is not presented in some order, it might be very hard to use.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo this was my first thought, but then I thought that if I’m having to create a separate answer I might as well do it so that clarity is maximised. Hence my idea to have a separate answer for each chapter.

Comment: Are you familiar with the right-click menu that (in a "Math Settings" submenu) offers some choices for MathJax rendering?

Comment: @hardmath no, where exactly is the right-click menu/Math Settings submenu?

Comment: Right-click (in a desktop browser) on any MathJax formatted math expression.  A pop-up menu appears with the Math Settings submenu, under which you can choose how MathJax rendering will work.  The setting is stored (cookie) on a per site/browser basis, so in fact I have a different renderer here on Meta.Math.SE than I do on Math.SE.

Comment: @hardmath thank you, switching to common HTML from HTML/CSS is a slight improvement.

Comment: @JohnMa (you most likely figured this out, but adding this just in case) the problem is not rendering of the final post. It is the TeX-processing in the preview pane. With enough TeX-code it reaches a point where pressing a single key causes a 2-3 second delay while the code is processed. It becomes progressively worse as the post grows longer. Good for you, if you have never suffered from this.

Comment: See for example [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2558/11619), [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4208/11619). Technical solutions exist, but my recollection is a bit shaky whether those work optimally. The people at MathJax worked on it hard (see Davide Cervone's posts).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : You mean the delay when one was editing right? I experienced that a lot when I use my older computer, but never for this new one.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The bookmarklet workaround in the linked answer is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: This is a very very irritating problem and I am glad someone discussed it here. Nowadays I type long answers in a text editor and copy paste it into MSE edit box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it is fine. My suggestion would be that you edit your current answer and indicate on top that it covers errata for chapters 1-9, say. On top of your new answer, you could indicate that it covers errata for chapters 10-blah, and that you are posting it as a separate answer to increase ease of search (and maybe also mention how the large size was making it difficult to edit the file efficiently). You can then repeat the process if this second answer ends up ballooning in size as well.

Although I don't feel it would be a big deal anyway, I think it would actually be less useful to have a separate entry per each chapter, since the overabundance of answers may make the page look cluttered and disorganized, which is in part the opposite of your goal, and may lead to duplication of effort, with other people posting answers that list errata you already had or were to include, rather than having them all in a single place.

(I imagine you are not opposed to others editing your answers to add further errata you may have missed in chapters you already have listed.)

Comment: I upvoted your answer for "the overabundance of answers may make the page look cluttered and disorganized, which is in part the opposite of your goal". That didn't occur to me, and I think you may be right. I am definitely not opposed to others editing my answers to add errata, it is a CW post after all.